# Mounted NFS doesn't stay mounted

Tags: 20.04, mount, nfs

When I mount the NFS onto a folder in my local PC, I'm able to see all the files and folders initially, but after a day or 2, the folder I mounted on just shows as an empty folder with nothing inside, and I have to remount again.

How do I fix this?

I'm using 20.04.2 LTS, mounted using `sudo mount -t nfs`

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question with further details. In particular, which version of Ubuntu are you referring to and an explanation as to how the share is mounted, manually or in fstab plus any other relevant detail.

Comment: Is there anything in [this resource](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-nfs-server-on-ubuntu/) which might help and have you followed all the steps? Again, [edit] your question with the steps you have taken, not add to the comment trail.